# Unexpected results on exception while doing file I/O

Tags: c++, file, file-io, exception

I have a small code with some file I/O

```
bool loadConfigFile(std::string configFileName)
{
    std::ifstream configFile;
    try
    {
        configFile.open(configFileName, std::ifstream::in);
        if(true != configFile.good())
        {
            throw std::exception("Problem with config file");
        }
    } catch (std::exception &e)
    {
        fprintf(stderr, "There was an error while opening the file: %s\n %s\n" , configFileName, e.what());
        configFile.close();
    }

    configFile.close();
    return true;
}
```

And everytime I launch the program without the file provided as a parameter I get some rubbish on output (random characters) or an unexpected error in runtime. What am I doing wrong here ?

Comment: I don't understand.  Rubbish on output?  Where?  From what line?

Comment: Perhaps you should add some validation code to check for the presence of the parameter value, and `return` `false` if it is not there.

Comment: `if(true != configFile.good())` Ouch! Better is `if (!configFile.is_open())`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`"%s"` expects an null terminated `char` array as its input but the code is passing `configFileName`, which is a `std::string`. Either use `std::string::.c_str()` or use `std::cerr` instead:

```
std::cerr << "There was an error while opening the file: "
          << configFileName << '\n'
          << e.what()       << '\n';
```

Note that the `ifstream` constructor has a variant that accepts the filename to open and the destructor will close the stream if it is open so the explicit calls to `open()` and `close()` can be omitted:

```
try
{
    std::ifstream configFile(configFileName);
    if (!configFile.is_open())
    {
        throw std::exception("Failed to open '" + configFileName + "'");
    }
}
catch (const std::exception& e)
{
    // Handle exception.
    std::cerr << e.what() << '\n';
    return false;
}
```

Comment: Thanks that's exactly what I needed. EDIT: you are right about the constructor but then I won't be able to access `configFile` outside the try block.

Comment: @Patryk, why do you need to? Access it inside the `try` block only where it is known to be valid.